# how to convert base64 to image by using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the base64 data for an image that i need to convert it into file type and send it to server can any one help me to fix this problem?

```
<textarea name="imgbase64" >data:image/png;base64,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</textarea>
```

I have to convert this base64 data to image and append to iploadimg and submit as encmultipart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload an embedded image with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391628/how-can-i-upload-an-embedded-image-with-javascript)

Comment: [Jquery Add image into div convert base64 string into thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26332467/1245497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var base64_string = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//...";
var img = document.createElement("img");
// added `width` , `height` properties to `img` attributes
img.width = "250px";
img.height = "250px";
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64_string;
var preview = document.getElementById("img_preview");
preview.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: i hope by using this code we can just display the image but here my requirement is with this i need the data64 to convert to file type

Comment: Its basically copy-paste from this **accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26332690/1245497)**. You should flag question as duplicate instead!