# How to convert a base64 image to a normal image

Tags: image, base64, html2canvas

I want to convert a base64 image to a normal image. I tried many solutions, but I did not succeed. Can anybody provide me with the solution for converting a base64 image to a normal image like jpg or png?

Actually, I am converting my `div` to an html2canvas image, and that image comes with base64 image with very long path.

For example:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkAAAAJACAYAAABlmtk2AAAgAElEQVR4Xu
3dQYoj5paEUdng7Zhemie1ipz00rwfg2nSUOPKvEdCdPD11IqreucPQZCT/u3j4+PPPx6P3x//D//vn8
fj389/dv/+9zxe/u9x//mt+ecvAvVH9DybvxvKhU//3/734+N//vrx42859K7s57/987v797/nBfJ/j/
vPb80/fxGoP6Ln2fzdUC58+jeARBCz/QAQEOP5IyDG80dAjOePgBjPHwEx3gBCQI33A1BBy+dvfprOXw
Utn7/5aTp/FbR8A8j8ON0PgAnpQP7Ex+H8mZAO5E98HM6fCelAA4j4PNwPwA3lQv6i59n83VAu5C96ns
3fDeVCA0j0npDtB/AERDiRP+A9IZr/ExDhRP6A94Ro/k9AhBMNIMB7RrQfwDMU7zfyv9s9I5n/MxTvN/
K/2z0jmf8zFO83GkB3u6ck+wE8hfF8JP8z3VOC+T+F8Xwk/zPdU4L5P4XxfKQBdKZ7TrAfwHMcr1fyv8
o9J5f/cxyvV/K/yj0nl/9zHK9XGkBXuSfl+gE8CfJ4Jv8j3JNi+T8J8ngm/yPck2L5PwnyeKYBdIR7Vq
6/oieZ/N3Q7mQv+h5dsG/AeQ9OF9YKFAD6Pz8HKw/TEgH8ic+DufPhHRgwb8BRBWw8EKBGkDWAUnXH9H
zbP5uKBfyFz3PLvg3gLwH5wsLBWoAnZ+fg/WHCelA/sTH4fyZkA4s+P/28fHx5x+Px+8k8abwP4/Hv59
f3b//PQ+Q/3vcf35r/vmLQP0RPc/m74Zy4dP//wBHqel8UTBFDwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert base64 to image by using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343196/how-to-convert-base64-to-image-by-using-jquery)

Comment: i tried many solution, can u explain me in details ?

Comment: I looked into base64 decode in Imagemagick last year without very much success. When I finally got it to work with php I found there was a file size limit. Something to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Your "image" appears to me to be corrupt. I can take an image, called `wizard.png` and create a base64 encoded version of it with a header like this:

```
{ echo "data:image/png;base64,"; openssl enc -base64 -in wizard.png; } > image.b64
```

and that gives me a file called `image.b64` that looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeAAAAKACAMAAABzFltgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
AwBQTFRF////9vf5/f3z9PTy8O/vuLi3h4aJe3qEjIyTnqGqlJSciIiVna2Jk5CP
m5yjsa6uu7zExsjVy8zT2drk5+ny6+zy29rYWVZYPEVvSFORNjuHODyViHZVlIxU
b2hUTko1LjB2MTVpNDl3PESJcm1pe4JlqpdvvsHJ0tLN4ODfXGFoWmbXS1W4Wmbn
ZnXrW2X1WGe4ybV04ttzUVvJsKlbUU5SWGaTbXKQrrG73+Dk7Ovs6OfkUVnaREq1
TVTTtalwPkWyR028jod0dHFvS1apSFBydIrQZXeyWGipz9DNYl1aLjF7S1TFQ0qp
P0ik16hUT1bZS1LMRUq7VFvlUk1KPUQnZXjIdYvpc4nYmJeYJCVcKix4PEKaLTGF
...
...
X+9XwFEV/w8Kj7AwotkslQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTpjcmVhdGUAMjAxNi0wMS0xM1Qx
MDoyMTowNyswMDowMJ4C96EAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6bW9kaWZ5ADIwMTYtMDEtMTNU
MTA6MjE6MDcrMDA6MDDvX08dAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

I can now convert that file back to a normal image using `ImageMagick`  with:

```
convert inline:image.b64 result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var base64_string = "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";


$("img").attr("src","data:image/png;base64," + base64_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img width="400" height="250"/>
```